# Keep getting repeat errors after loading libraries

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr

I am trying to write this code but I get the error that ggplot2 is not found. I reload the library, rerun the code, and then I get that %>% is not found. I have loaded library(dplyr) multiple times. When I try and do this again, I keep going back and forth to one not being found, after reloading both libraries.

Plot the hotness score vs the number of active listings in every county in the country and identify observations in each year using different colors.

```
library(ggplot2)
df_separate <- df_raw %>%
 separate("hotness_score", "active_listing_count") %>%
   ggplot2(data = df_separate, 
       mapping = aes(x = hotness_score, 
                     y = active_listing_count))
```

Answer (score 1):

The package name is `ggplot2` and the function is `ggplot`.  Also, as the data separated is not assigned to a new object, specify the `data = .`

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyr)

df_raw %>%
  separate("hotness_score", "active_listing_count") %>%
  ggplot(data = .,  mapping = aes(x = hotness_score, 
                 y = active_listing_count))
```